# here-api Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addDomListener' of undefined at

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-5, here-api

I am trying to integrate here-api map into my rails 5 app. Some background I have developed a similar app page with google maps in the past following a course successfully. Using here-api as an alternative as google recently be charging at certain levels.

I have successfully been able to display a here map with lng and lat hard coded. however 
I am getting a blank screen were the map once was when I try to integrate the rails database info lng & lng. trying the same  naming conventions and method as I have done in the past with integrating google. I am using/used gem 'geocoder', '~> 1.4'. as I am converting the address from the form into lng ltd that I had to for google map. 
the chrome console log has an error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addDomListener' of undefined
at line: 
H.Map.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

expected outcome: using addDom to initialize when one changes there address it updates the db with the new lng lat and using var location to fetch the lng & lat. in place of the hard coded coordinates that was successful. expecting the here-api to use those lng, lat and it display the map same as the hard coded version. However I get a blank screen.

working: The correct lng & lat show up in the db when the address changes and in chrome inspection the lng & lat are in the html.

For google I had to use this:

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

for here I used(not sure if its correct method):
H.Map.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

Below is the head portion  of app thats not working

```
<script src="http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-core.js"
          type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-service.js"
          type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-ui.js"
          type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
        href="http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-ui.css" />
```

below is the partial view html.erb

```
<div class="card-body">
    <div id="mapContainer" style="width: 100%; height: 400px"></div>

    <script>
        var platform = new H.service.Platform({
            'app_id': 'my_appid_info-FROM_HERE',
            'app_code': 'myappcodeinfo_FROM HERE'
        });

        // Obtain the default map types from the platform objec

        var maptypes = platform.createDefaultLayers();



        // Instantiate (and display) a map object:
        function initialize() {
            var location = {lat: <%= @location.latitude %>, lng: <%= 
@location.longitude %>};
            var map = new 
H.Map(document.getElementById('mapContainer'), maptypes.normal.map, {
                center: location,
                zoom: 10

            });
        }


       H.Map.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>


  </div>
```

Many thank for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such function `H.Map.event.addDomListener`.

If you want to call `initialize` on window load event, use:

```
 window.addEventListener('load', initialize);
```

Regarding map events, HERE has some methods under the `H.mapevents` package. Make sure to load `mapsjs-mapevents.js` if you need them. This would be useful for operations like adding an event listener on a map object, or even enabling events on the map like panning, zooming, etc.

You can refer to the [javascript examples](https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/maps-js/v3.0/maps/map-at-specified-location).

Comment: Thank you upon replacing it w/ window.addEventListener('load', initialize); I now have the area from the db. unable to get panning and controls as its apparnet I dont have a strong grasp of JS.

Comment: I had tried a few things refering to your JS examples link and upon entering: var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));

// Create the default UI components
var ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, defaultLayers);

Comment: now that I have a still image of map need to have UI tried for pan etc, The error from chrome console is uncaught ReferenceError: map is not defined. what do I refer to or write to refer to my elements above for thes code below as I have it now  
    window.addEventListener('load', initialize);
            var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new 
    H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));

            // Create the default UI components
            var ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, 
    defaultLayers);

Comment: You'll have to add the default behavior and UI within your initialize function where you also have the reference to the map. If you try to do that after just registering the initialize event handler there is no map yet.

Comment: yes I had moved the ui and behaviour inside my function initialize() {..} and it worked as expected now thanks